# ASP.NET Display part of a PDF

Tags: pdf, asp.net-2.0

I need to display a PDF in an ASP.NET web page and specify the Zoom, X/Y coordinates and page to display. Can this be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use Adobe reader and enter parameters when opening the PDF:

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to pull it off with, say, a Flash PDF viewer (for example, see Scribd) for the best cross-platform (Windows, OS X, Linux) solution.

If you just want to embed PDF in a web page, you might have to use an iFrame and use browser capabilities (Adobe Reader plugin, Google Chrome PDF reader) if you want to support all browsers.